# Divide costs by months considering two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Considering 2 projects, I have to divide de cost of a project by the number of months between 2 dates, and output the result in the correct months, from January to December.

The output table must show the results of a single year, if a end date ends in the next year it must calculate only until December.

Here's an example:

[image: Example of Final Table fro 2020]

Comment: Define "months" in this context. Calendar months? something else? SQL Server's `datediff()` function (e.g.,, `datediff(month, startDate, endDate)` will give you the count of month _*boundaries*_ crossed between the two dates — `datediff(month, '2019-01-31', '2019-02-01') returns `1`.

Comment: By months I mean the number of diferente months between 2 dates, not the number of months for 30 days. From 01/01 until 15/02 it should be 2 months, not 1,5 months

Comment: Then `datediff()` is your friend: if you say `declare @months = 1 + datediff( month, '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01' )` you'll get the desired value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by using a series of case expressions:

```
select a.*,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=1 and month(end_date)>=1 then Cost/no_months end as January,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=2 and month(end_date)>=2 then Cost/no_months end as February,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=3 and month(end_date)>=3 then Cost/no_months end as March,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=4 and month(end_date)>=4 then Cost/no_months end as April,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=5 and month(end_date)>=5 then Cost/no_months end as May,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=6 and month(end_date)>=6 then Cost/no_months end as June,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=7 and month(end_date)>=7 then Cost/no_months end as July,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=8 and month(end_date)>=8 then Cost/no_months end as August,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=9 and month(end_date)>=9 then Cost/no_months end as Spetember,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=10 and month(end_date)>=10 then Cost/no_months end as October,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=11 and month(end_date)>=11 then Cost/no_months end as November,
       CASE WHEN month(start_date)<=12 and month(end_date)>=12 then Cost/no_months end as December
from tableA a
```

Comment: Your example code as case *expressions*, not case *statements*.

Comment: Imagine Project A start date is 10/12/2019, this solution does not return the results of January and February.